# Match uneven number of escape symbols

Tags: regex, pcre, backreference

I need to match C++ preprocessor statements. Now, preprocessor statements may span multiple lines:

```
#define foobar \
    "something glorious"
```

This final backslash may be escaped so the following results in two separate lines:

```
#define foobar \\
No longer in preprocessor.
```

The question is how I can match the explicit line continuation efficiently. I have the following expression which I *think* works. Basically, it tests whether the number of backslashes is odd. Is this correct? Can it be done more efficiently?

```
/
    [^\\]           # Something that's not an escape character, followed by …
    (?<escape>\\*?) # … any number of escapes, …
    (?P=escape)     # … twice (i.e. an even number).
    \\ \n           # Finally, a backslash and newline.
/x
```

(I'm using PHP so PCRE rules apply but I'd appreciate answers in *any* Regex vernacular.)

Comment: Do you want to match the entire preprocessor statement or just the explicit line continuation?

Comment: Just the explicit line continuation. Reason is complicated; basically, I’m using a state machine that uses regular expressions for its transitions and I’m already inside the state representing the preprocessing instruction. I now need to prevent the machine from leaving the state prematurely at the end of the line by consuming the explicit line continuation. I need the regular expression to consume it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're making it more difficult than it needs to be. Try this:

```
/
  (?<!\\)    # not preceded by a backslash
  (?:\\\\)*  # zero or more escaped backslashes
  \\ \n      # single backslash and linefeed
/x
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was about to suggest. +1

Comment: Man, that’s so obvious. Thanks a lot for putting me straight.